# SharePoint search in customs list

Tags: search, field, lookup

Need to add search fields in SharePoint 2010 like user search to search from another list which have more that 1000 company name

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please share a code example that should do what you're trying to do, and where does it fail. If you haven't already, please visit https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you,I created a customs list with many field. one field  drown down list , this list is contain around 10,000 companies. I am trying to add search field  for this 10,000 companies but i was not able to. kindly advise.